# Quarkus unit-testing and properties

Tags: unit-testing, quarkus, system-properties

I have a basic question about Quarkus testing, I would like to execute the command `./mvnw clean test` but I need to use a token to init the application.

I have configured `application-test.properties` file to store the token:

`discord.token=XYZ`

So, in my code I was expecting to be able to retrieve the value of the `discord.token` property:

```java
@ConfigProperty(name = "discord.token")
private String token;
```

Is it possible? if not, how can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can instead put your `application.properties` file in `src/test/resources` instead of `application-test.properties` in `src/main/resources`

You can also use `mvn -Dquarkus.config.locations=/tmp/foo.properties test`

Answer (score 0):

The `dev` profile is used by dev mode (`./mvnw quarkus:dev`). If you want to define a property for your tests, you need to use the `test` profile.

You can do that either with a suffixed file as you did (but with the `-test` suffix i.e. `application-test.properties`) or use `%test.` in front of your properties (`%test.discord.token=XYZ`) in the regular `application.properties`.

See https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#profiles for more information.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the question, I have changed application-dev.properties to application-test.properties in the text (by the way, the result is the same)